# login forum/site e compartilhamento de session

Tags: php

tenho um site e um fórum, e gostaria que os usuários usassem o mesmo login e senha em ambos. e se possível também gostaria que ambos partilhassem da mesma sessão, para não precisar fazer login 2 vezes.

Comment: Poste o codigo do que você já fez ou suas dificuldades no processo.

Comment: a minha dificuldade principal é fazer a mesma sessão do site servir para o fórum. o que acontece é o seguinte, tenho um servidor em java que conecta com um banco de dados e o site pega os dados desse banco para fazer login, já o fórum tem seu próprio banco de dados, e quanto ao session não envia de uma pagina para outra pois os dois tem arquivos diferentes de enviar a session

Comment: Muito ampla a pergunta, Seja mais específico com o problema, complemente a pergunta clicando em Editar. Sobre a resposta, procure sobre SSO - Single Sign On.

Answer (score 0):

Fazer isto usando sessão não é possível, a sessão permanece ativa somente no domínio que a criou, no máximo o que poderia ser feito seria compartilhar esta sessão para utilização nos subdomínios do domínio em questão. Para fazer que usem o mesmo Login e Senha você pode usar cookies. Um exemplo desta utilização segue abaixo:

ob_start(); // utilizando este comando não terá problemas  caso a pagina contenha conteudo html,

```
if($acao==logar){
include "config.php";

$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$senha = $_POST["senha"];

$sql = mysql_query("select * from tabela where usuario='$usuario' AND    senha=MD5('$senha')"); /* verifico se o usuário e a senha estão corretos */
$sql2 = mysql_query("select `usuario`, `senha`, `nivel` from tabela where 
usuario='$usuario' LIMIT 0,1", $conexao); /* verifico o nivel do usuário 
logado */
$busca = mysql_num_rows($sql); /*verifico se ocorreu resultado*/
$array = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);/*se ocorreu crio um array para os dados 
recebidos */
$usuario = $array["usuario"];
$senha = $array["senha"];
$nivel = $array["nivel"];


if(($busca > 0) && ($array > 0)){ /* crio os cookies */
setcookie("usuario", $usuario);
setcookie("senha", $senha);
setcookie("nivel", $nivel);
header("location: admin.php");
}
else{
echo"Erro ao se logar.";
}
}
```

Espero ter ajudado! Abraços!